# How to edit AjaxFileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using `AjaxFileUpload` control to upload multiple image files. What I am doing is saving the file into a folder and then inserting it into the database. My table fields are `id`,`url`, `alt`. I also want to enter Alternate Text for the image so that it displays as description for the image. How can I edit it in `AjaxFileUpload` Control. For each image I upload an a textbox to accept alternate text should appear. How can I do this. Is it possible to do so.??

Here's my aspx code:

```
<div id="sliderinsert" style="position:absolute; padding-bottom:5px; background-color:gray; top: 24px; left: 13px; 
    width: 695px; height: 300px; margin-bottom: 1px; overflow:visible">

        <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload style="position:absolute; width:695px; overflow:auto;max-height:600px"  MaximumNumberOfFiles="7" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"  
            id="ajaxUpload1"  OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload1_UploadComplete" runat="server" Width="633px"/>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

    </div>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
protected void ajaxUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
     id+=1;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/Gallery/" + filename);
    ajaxUpload1.SaveAs(filepath);

    string Insert = "Insert into slider (slid,slurl) values (@id,@IMAGE_PATH)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Insert, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMAGE_PATH", filepath);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can create one gridview in which you show filename and add textbox into gridview and save all alter text.

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi.. So you are telling to load the AjaxFileUpload control in the Grid and along with that a Textbox to accept the Alternate Text.

Comment: In AjaxFileUpload is  AsyncFileUpload. You can add more then one file at a time. so problem is if you wanna add different alter text for each file then use normal fileupload with textbox into gridview itemtemplete field

Comment: see below link :http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ajaxFileUpload/ajaxFileUpload.aspx
Add save into database operation after uploading all files...

Comment: Single file uploader with gridview demo
http://www.dotnetfox.com/Articles.aspx?id=1008

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi.. Oh so when using AjaxFileUpload and uploading multiple files we cannot add any other info with that data right? The single file uploader was good. Thank you.. I will try it...

Comment: You can use it..But it's take more research work.. Compare to single fileupload is better option if you need different alter text for each file which you upload.

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi.. Yea that is the better option but when multiple files are to be uploaded it results in time consuming work. Well if there is way left then I have to opt for this Itself.. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32801/discussion-between-saroop-trivedi-and-kaushik)

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi.. Sorry to say but Am using company's network where they have blocked all the chat applications. I will try connecting u after I reach home..

Comment: Hi
Kaushik
yes you can use the ajaxtoolkit
First you upload all files and perform the insert operatin
after that call one gridview in which show file name and give user to add alter textbox functionality...
CHeck this link
asp.net/ajaxLibrary/…
1. upload all files through ajax control
2.Save all files name
3.fill gridview by name for file
4.add one textbox column with each file name into gridview
5.add text for each image
6.update all text on one save button
hope this will helpful to you

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi.. The idea seems great.. But the link you provided was just to install the ajaxtoolkit.. is der any working example in the link you provided??? :)

Comment: check AjaxFileUpload Demonstration